# Problem opening PDF files on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, pdf

My organization implements a Sharepoint Server 2013 On Premise installation as collaborative platform.  Since we migrated all our websites from SharePoint 2010 to 2013, many users have been facing a very strange error regarding PDF files: when they click on a PDF file within a library, the browser redirects to the upper level folder instead of opening the file. Has anyone here ever faced the same issue? Could you please help me to solve it?

Comment: All PDFs do this?  All web browsers do this (IE, FF, Chrome, Edge)?  Does a newly uploaded PDF to the doc lib exhibit the same thing as well?

Comment: Hi Mike. First of all, let me correct something about my description: the users are not redirected to the upper level folder of the document library but to the root folder of the current library.

Comment: Regarding your other questions: it happens with every PDF file, including the newly uploaded ones. I tested the issue in a user computer that had additionally installed Chrome (all our users have IE 11) and it only happened in IE. But the most interesting thing is that it works correctly when changing the document mode to Edge. Finally, it also works fine when right-clicking on a PDF and selecting "open in a new tab".